# Oozie workflow for hive action

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I am using oozie to execute few hive queries one after another and if a query fails it will send error email that a particular hive query is failed.

Now I have to implement another email triggers based on the result of each hive query. So how can we do that ? Its like if a query returns any result then send the results to the email and continue executing remaining hive queries. There should be no stoppings of oozie workflow execution irrespective of query returns value or not.

In short, if it returns value then send email and continue if it didnt return value also it should continue executing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make decisions based on previous step its better to use shell actions(*hive -e* option to execute query) along with **capture_output** tag in oozie. Or better use java actions with hive jdbc connection to execute hive queries where you can utilize java for doing all logical looping and decision making.

As oozie doesn't support cycles/loops of execution you might need to repeat  the email action in workflow based on the decision making and flow.

Comment: I have used java action to capture output. It worked fine. I think we should write the data into a properties file so than next action in oozie can read that.

Comment: Yes, we should write to the oozie provided property file.